# Filtering and grouping with angularJS group count

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Given the following data:

```
[
{"Id": 3, "Name":"Image1.jpg", "AssetType":0, "Grouping": {"GroupingId": 4, "Name":"Other"}},
{"Id": 7, "Name":"Document1.jpg", "AssetType":2, "Grouping": {"GroupingId": 4, "Name":"Other"}},
{"Id": 8, "Name":"Video1.jpg", "AssetType":1, "Grouping": {"GroupingId": 4, "Name":"Other"}},
{"Id": 6, "Name":"Image2.jpg", "AssetType":0, "Grouping": {"GroupingId": 1, "Name":"Facebook"}},
]
```

I wanted to list separate groups of assets types, so I used the following ng-repeat:

```
<div class="group" ng-repeat="asset in assets | filterBy : ['AssetType'] : 0  "
    <b>{{ asset.Grouping.Name}}</b><br />
    {{ asset.Name }}
</div>
```

This gets me the following:

```
Other
Image1.jpg
Facebook
Image2.jpg
```

Now, I wanted to group by the grouping name, to test if there was only one group for this asset type.  If there was only one, I was not going to show the grouping name, so I added a group by to the ng-repeat statement:

```
<div class="group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in assets | filterBy : ['AssetType'] : 0  | groupBy : 'Grouping.Name' ">
    <b>{{ key }}</b> - {{ numGroups(key) }}<br />
    <div ng-repeat="asset in value ">
        {{ asset.Name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I added a function to get the count of keys for this filtered group, I got something unexpected:

```
Other - 5
Image1.jpg
Facebook - 8
Image2.jpg
```

numGroups is defined like this:

```
 $scope.numGroups = function (key) {
    return Object.keys(key).length;
}
```

I was expecting the length of keys to be 2 (Other and Facebook) but instead it looks like it is iterating all the items of the array.

Is there any way to get the count of group keys after a filter has been applied?

**There is a way!**

Here's how the solution worked out:

```
$scope.numGroups = function (map) {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach(map, function () { count++; });
    return count;
}
```

and the Html

```
<div class="group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in images = (assets | filterBy : ['AssetType'] : 0  | groupBy: 'Grouping.Name')  ">
    <div class="groupName" ng-hide="numGroups(images) == 1"><b>{{ key }}</b></div>
    <div ng-repeat="asset in value">
        {{ asset.Name }} - Brand {{ asset.Brand.Name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function 'numGroups' you are getting the length of the 'Grouping.Name' String, it could be fixed if you use this:

```
<div class="group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in grouped = (assets | groupBy : 'Grouping.Name') ">
        <b>{{key}}</b> - {{numGroups(grouped)}} <br />
        <div ng-repeat="asset in value">
            {{ asset.Name}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

And a tricky way of your noumGroups function:

```
            $scope.numGroups = function(map){
                                    var count = 0;
                                    angular.forEach(map, function(){
                                        count++;
                                    })
                                    return count;
                                }
```

Comment: That returns the count of items underneath the group.  I'm looking for the count of group keys after the filter has been applied.

Comment: @Josh I edited the answer, it does what you need but I hope you could fine a better way of do it

Comment: Awesome.  I'll update my answer with the filters applied for everyone to see.